# Algebraic set correspondence between projective and affine topology (Hartshorne Proposition 1.2.2.)

Tags: algebraic-geometry

For an open set $U$ in $\mathbb{P}^n$, Let $\phi: U \to \mathbb{A}^n$ be defined by $\phi (a_0,...,a_n) = (\frac{a_0}{a_i},...,\frac{a_n}{a_i})$ for $a_i$ non-zero and $\frac{a_i}{a_i}$ omitted.

Let $\alpha: \mathbb{P}^n \to k[y_1,...,y_n]$ be defined by $\alpha (f) = f(1,y_1,...,y_n)$ for $f$ a homogenous element of the $n+1$ polynomial ring $k[x_0,...,x_n]$ over some algebraically closed field $k$. For $Y = Z(T)$ a closed algebraic set in $\mathbb{P}^n$, Hartshorne says it is a 'straightforward check' to see that $\phi(Y) = Z(\alpha(T))$. Apparently it isn't straightforward enough, since even though I can verify it for specific cases I don't know how to prove this holds in general. So my question is: how can I prove this holds for arbitrary $Y$?

Comment: Please put the **entire** math expression inside the dollar signs so MathJax applies to all of it. It is very odd to leave brackets, colons, and other symbols which are part of math expressions outside the math formatting.

Answer (score 2):

First, your open set $U$ should be a specific open set: $D(x_i)$, the set where $x_i\neq 0$. Next, your map $\alpha$ is not correctly defined: the text defines it from the set of homogeneous elements of $k[x_0,\cdots,x_n]$ to $k[y_1,\cdots,y_n]$ and specializes to the case $i=0$.

To check this claim, suppose $[a_0:\cdots:a_n]$ is a point of $Y$ with $a_0\neq 0$. Then $\phi([a_0:\cdots:a_n])=(\frac{a_1}{a_0},\frac{a_2}{a_0},\cdots,\frac{a_n}{a_0})$, and for any homogeneous polynomial $f$ in $T$, we have $$\alpha(f)(\frac{a_1}{a_0},\frac{a_2}{a_0},\cdots,\frac{a_n}{a_0})=f(1,\frac{a_1}{a_0},,\cdots,\frac{a_n}{a_0})=a_0^{-\deg f}f(a_0,a_1,\cdots,a_n)=0.$$ As $a_0\neq 0$, we must have $f(a_0,\cdots,a_n)=0$, and $\phi(Y)\subset Z(\alpha(T))$.

Conversely, if $(y_1,\cdots,y_n)\in Z(\alpha(T))$, then for every $f\in T$ we have $f(1,y_1,\cdots,y_n)=0$, or $[1:y_1:\cdots:y_n]\in Z(T)=Y$, and so $Z(\alpha(T))\subset \phi(Y)$.

As you can see, this is just definition-unwinding.